# To global using directive refactoring

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-6.0, c#-10.0

I would like to migrate my projects to .NET 6 and C# 10. As a part of this migration I would like to use `global using` directives.

Has Visual Studio 2022 any tool or help to do a "to `global using` directive" refactoring?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ReSharper/Jetbrains is again one step ahead with it's 'Extract Global Using refactoring'.

If you want to know more about it https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Refactorings__Extract_Global_Using.html

Answer (score 2):

I don't think, there is any tool which does `"To global using" directive` refactoring, but you can try alternate way,

1. Replace `using` block with empty string in entire project, you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>

[image]

2. Now you can add `global using` in any `.cs` file or you put all global using in a separate file called `globalusings.cs`

**Note:**

- Find + Replace will add additional empty line in all `.cs` files.

Answer (score 2):

Making namespace global should render corresponding using unnecessary in other files. Remove unnecessary usings diagnostic allows you to select the scope for the fix:

[image]

If for some reason the diagnostic is not shown you can enable it via [`.editorconfig`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/create-portable-custom-editor-options?view=vs-2022) via rule code ([IDE0005](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/style-rules/ide0005)):

```
# IDE0005: Using directive is unnecessary.
dotnet_diagnostic.IDE0005.severity = suggestion
```

Comment: Many thx, that is a good idea, but the half of the story, I mean we must create the global usings manually. You are right, then a using directive removal cleanup (either VS build in via editorconfig, or 3rd party) will do the heavy lifting.

Comment: @guru-stron Do you know when a using statement should be kept in a file instead of moved to `globalusings.cs`? Is there an advantage to not move everything into `globalusings.cs`?

Comment: @surfmuggle you mean global usings?

Comment: @guru-stron Yes. Are there any advantages to declare a `using foo.bar` statement as a global using statement and move it from `n` files to a central `globalusings.cs` other than to not have this `using foo.bar` in `n` files?

Comment: @surfmuggle oh, you mean `using` vs `global using` (personally I even prefer adding `Using` xml element into csproj instead of `global using` in some file). The main advantage - reducing number of code lines with corresponding benefits - some are described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75170889/2501279). Despite IDEs being able to reduce the clutter of working with namespaces still there is some (and you do not always work with IDE - for example when looking at the diff in the github).

Answer (score 2):

I've just faced to the same problem and wrote simple console application to solve this problem.

```cs
using System.Text;

if (args.Length == 0 || string.IsNullOrEmpty(args[0]))
    throw new ArgumentException("You must specify directory");
var directoryForScan = args[0];
if (!Directory.Exists(directoryForScan))
{
    throw new ArgumentException($"{directoryForScan} not exist");
}

var filesEnumeration = Directory.EnumerateFiles(directoryForScan, "*.cs", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
var directorySeparator = Path.DirectorySeparatorChar;
var usingSet = new SortedSet<string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
foreach (var filePath in filesEnumeration.Where(it => !it.Contains($"{directorySeparator}bin{directorySeparator}") 
                                                  && !it.Contains($"{directorySeparator}obj{directorySeparator}")))
{
    await ProcessUsingAsync(filePath, usingSet);
}

var resultFilePath = Path.Combine(directoryForScan,"GlobalUsings.cs");

await using var resultStream = new FileStream(resultFilePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Write);
await using var writer = new StreamWriter(resultStream, Encoding.UTF8);
foreach (var item in usingSet)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
    await writer.WriteAsync("global ");
    await writer.WriteLineAsync(item);
}

await resultStream.FlushAsync();

static async Task ProcessUsingAsync(string filePath, ISet<string> usingSet)
{
    await using var fileStream = File.OpenRead(filePath);
    using var reader = new StreamReader(fileStream);
    string? currentLine;
    do
    {
        currentLine = await reader.ReadLineAsync();
        if (currentLine is not null 
            && currentLine.StartsWith("using")
            && currentLine.EndsWith(";") 
            && !currentLine.Contains(" static ") 
            && !currentLine.Contains("="))
        {
            usingSet.Add(currentLine);
        }
    } while (currentLine != null);
}
```